# Checking in code from Subversion to CVS

Tags: svn, import, cvs, dump

We're managing source code here using SVN and we have a client that uses CVS who has requested we occasionally check-in code from our SVN to their CVS repository. We're not looking to migrate to CVS but rather somehow dump from SVN into CVS on occasion. Is there a manageable process to dump SVN into CVS? I imagine it may entail doing an SVN dump and then committing that dump to CVS somehow (I'm familiar with SVN but have never touched CVS).

Any advice would be appreciated!

Thanks!
Dan

Answer (score 2):

Never done this myself but a little Google'ing turned up these two scripts with the same name (unfortunately?) :

- http://svn2cvs.tigris.org/

  > This script will allows you to commit changes made to Subversion repository to (read-only) CVS repository manually or from Subversion's post-commit hook.
- http://wiki.freebsd.org/svn2cvs

  > The basic purpose of the FreeBSD svn2cvs system is to replicate commits in the FreeBSD Subversion repository to the old CVS repository. svn2cvs preserves full commit information (as much as CVS allows) [...]: